# Rewrite Block Class that is rewriting Mage Core Class

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to override a Block class called `Smartwave_Megamenu_Block_Topmenu`, which is declared like the following:

```
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <navigation>Smartwave_Megamenu_Block_Navigation</navigation>
                <!-- v1.4-1.6 -->
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
        <page>
            <rewrite>
                <html_topmenu>Smartwave_Megamenu_Block_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
                <!-- v1.7 -->
            </rewrite>
        </page>
        <megamenu>
            <class>Smartwave_Megamenu_Block</class>
        </megamenu>
    </blocks>
```

As you can see this `config.xml`-Block node is rewriting `html_topmenu` of `Mage_Core`.

However, if I try to rewrite `megamenu` like the following:

```
    <blocks>
        <vendor_template>
            <class>Vendor_Template_Block</class>
        </vendor_template>
        <megamenu>
            <rewrite>
                <topmenu>Vendor_Template_Block_Topmenu</topmenu>
            </rewrite>
        </megamenu>
    </blocks>
```

The same old Class is still loaded. Why is this happening and how can I rewrite this Block Class properly?

I've cleared caches, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way not working. You need to overwrite the core class and extend **Smartwave_Megamenu_Block_Topmenu** class.

Ex: First comment out the following line from **Smartwave_Megamenu** module config.xml

```
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <navigation>Smartwave_Megamenu_Block_Navigation</navigation>
                <!-- v1.4-1.6 -->
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
        <!--
        <page>
            <rewrite>
                <html_topmenu>Smartwave_Megamenu_Block_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
            </rewrite>
        </page>
        -->
        <megamenu>
            <class>Smartwave_Megamenu_Block</class>
        </megamenu>
    </blocks>
```

Now overwrite your module config:

```
    <blocks>
        <vendor_template>
            <class>Vendor_Template_Block</class>
        </vendor_template>
        <page>
            <rewrite>
                <html_topmenu>Vendor_Template_Block_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
            </rewrite>
        </page>
    </blocks>
```

After that :

```
class Vendor_Template_Block_Topmenu extends Smartwave_Megamenu_Block_Topmenu
{

}
```

Comment: Whoof, what a bummer. Usually Magento tends to be better then this... :/ Has worked perfectly fine! Thank you very much!